# Generalized Additive Model result interpretation

Tags: r, time-series, econometrics, generalized-additive-model

[image]

This is result from Generalized Additive Model. I am trying to look at the relationship between the number of deaths(dependent variable) and PM2.5 (independent variable) with lag effect.  However, I do not know how to interpret it. Is the p-value is important in this Model? What is important and how the result should be ? 
Please explain me if someone who is good at GAM.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if none of the terms in your model are significant except for the smoothing terms for time and month suggesting a nonlinear relationship over time (non-linear trend) coupled with a seasonal signal of some kind. You're R-Squared is pretty low at 18%.